# Why does the NSAttributedString format the whole of my string?

Tags: ios, swift, format, nsattributedstring

I have a large body of text that looks like this:

[image: this] using this code:

```
detail2TextView.text = textAnhorig.chapter12
```

The text style is set to iOS's default text style called `body`.

Using code, I successfully format the quoted text to italics. This is the code:

```
//function that format part of text
func formatfunc(chapter: String, boldStart: Int, boldLength: Int, italicsStart: Int, italicsLength: Int) -> NSAttributedString {
    let bold = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 17)
    let italics = UIFont.italicSystemFont(ofSize: 17)

    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString.init(string: chapter)
    attributedString.addAttribute(.font, value: bold, range: NSRange.init(location: boldStart, length: boldLength))
    attributedString.addAttribute(.font, value: italics, range: NSRange.init(location: italicsStart, length: italicsLength))

    return attributedString
}

//calling function
let formated = textAnhorig.formatfunc(chapter: textAnhorig.chapter12, boldStart: 0, boldLength: 0, italicsStart: 0, italicsLength: 85)

//presenting edited text
detail2TextView.attributedText = formated
```

This works fine, but the problem is that the rest of the string for some reason is formated into a completely different style - smaller and possibly with another font (can't really tell). You can see the result here:

[image: here.]

What happened and how do I stop it from happening and just keep the rest of the text the way it was?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set a base font for the whole string first, then apply the bold and italic font to the desired range.

```
func formatfunc(chapter: String, boldStart: Int, boldLength: Int, italicsStart: Int, italicsLength: Int) -> NSAttributedString {
    let bold = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 17)
    let italics = UIFont.italicSystemFont(ofSize: 17)

    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: chapter, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)])
    attributedString.addAttribute(.font, value: bold, range: NSRange(location: boldStart, length: boldLength))
    attributedString.addAttribute(.font, value: italics, range: NSRange(location: italicsStart, length: italicsLength))

    return attributedString
}
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks man, it worked like a charm! :) One thing though, `NSAttributedString.Key.font:` gave me an error, but I changed it to `NSAttributedStringKey.font:` and it solved the issue. Don't know why. Again, big thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Depends on the version of Swift you are using.